# Fixed points of rational continuous piecewise affine maps

Tags: convex-polytopes, fixed-point-theorems, rational-points

Say that a compact convex polytope is *rational* if is the intersection of half-spaces whose bounding hyperplanes are the zero-sets of affine functions of the coordinates with rational coefficients. Say that a continuous function $f$ from a rational compact convex polytope $K$ into itself is *rational continuous piecewise affine* if there exists a dissection of $K$ into finitely many rational polytopes $K_1,\dots,K_n$ (whose interiors are disjoint and whose union is $K$) such that for all $1 \leq i \leq n$ the restriction of $f$ to $K_i$ is an affine map with rational coefficients. (People sometimes write "piecewise linear" where I write "piecewise affine" and abbreviate "continuous piecewise linear" as "cpl".)

The Brouwer fixed point theorem assures us that such a map $f$ must have a fixed point. But must it have a fixed point with rational coordinates?

Comment: Isn't the graph of $f$ itself a rational polytope? Hence a fixed-point is locally given by the intersection of two affine subspaces with rational coefficients. If it has a solution, then it has a rational solution (by Cramer's formula, say). Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I was the one who was missing something basic. (I should probably sleep on questions like this before posting them to MO...) You may post your comment as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fixed-point is obtained as the intersection of two affine subspaces (a piece of the graph of $f$ and the identity graph) whose equations are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore Cramer's formula (applied to a maximal rank subsystem) ensures that if there exists a solution then there exists a rational one.